# Change to the previous day date in python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, datetime

I'm working on my python script to get the strings from the button objects so I can use it to set the date formats with the time that I got from the strings to store it in the lists. When I get the strings from the button objects, I want to set the date for each string, example: `29/08/2017 11:30PM`, `30/08/2017 12:00AM`, `30/08/2017 12:30AM`.

When I try this:

```
if day_date >= 0 and day_date <= 6:
   if epg_time3 == '12:00AM':
      if day_date > 0:  
         currentday = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days = 0)
         nextday = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days = self.program_day)

         if currentday != nextday:
            epg_time_1 = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days = self.program_day + 1)
            epg_time_2 = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days = self.program_day + 1)
            epg_time_3 = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days = self.program_day + 1)
        elif currentday == nextday:
             epg_time_1 = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days = self.program_day)
             epg_time_2 = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days = self.program_day - 1)
             epg_time_3 = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days = self.program_day - 1)
```

It will show the output:

```
self.epg_time_1
['29/08/2017 11:00PM']
self.epg_time_2
['29/08/2017 11:30PM']
self.epg_time_3
['29/08/2017 12:00AM']
```

When I'm calling the EPG_Times function again, it will show the output like this:

```
self.epg_time_1
['30/08/2017 11:00PM']
self.epg_time_2
['30/08/2017 11:30PM']
self.epg_time_3
['30/08/2017 12:00AM']
```

It should be:

```
self.epg_time_1
['30/08/2017 11:00PM']
self.epg_time_2
['30/08/2017 11:30PM']
self.epg_time_3
['31/08/2017 12:00AM']
```

As you can see the time `12:00AM` is the next day so I want to set it to `31` not `30`. I have changed from `days = self.program_day + 1` to `days = self.program_day - 1`, but when the strings show `11:00PM`, `11:30PM` and  `12:00AM` from the variables `epg_time_1`, `epg_time_2` and `epg_time_3`, it will show the output like this:

```
self.epg_time_1
['30/08/2017 11:00PM']
self.epg_time_2
['30/08/2017 11:30PM']
self.epg_time_3
['30/08/2017 12:00AM']
```

Here is the full code:

```
self.program_day = list()

def EPG_Times(self):
     self.epg_time_1 = list()
     self.epg_time_2 = list()
     self.epg_time_3 = list()
     epg_time1 = str(self.getControl(344).getLabel())
     epg_time2 = str(self.getControl(345).getLabel())
     epg_time3 = str(self.getControl(346).getLabel())
     day_date = self.program_day
     day = ''
     month = ''
     year = ''    

     if day_date >= 0 and day_date <= 6:
         if epg_time3 == '12:00AM':    

            if day_date == 0:
                if epg_time1 == '12:00AM':
                   epg_time_1 = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days = self.program_day + 1)
                   epg_time_2 = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days = self.program_day + 1)
                   epg_time_3 = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days = self.program_day + 1)
                 else:
                     epg_time_1 = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days = self.program_day)
                     epg_time_2 = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days = self.program_day)
                     epg_time_3 = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days = self.program_day + 1)

             else:                      
                 currentday = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days = 0)
                 nextday = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days = self.program_day)

                 if currentday != nextday:
                    epg_time_1 = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days = self.program_day + 1)
                    epg_time_2 = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days = self.program_day + 1)
                    epg_time_3 = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days = self.program_day + 1)
                 elif currentday == nextday:
                     epg_time_1 = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days = self.program_day)
                     epg_time_2 = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days = self.program_day - 1)
                     epg_time_3 = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days = self.program_day - 1)


              epg1_day = epg_time_1.strftime("%d")
              epg1_month = epg_time_1.strftime("%m")
              epg1_year = epg_time_1.strftime("%Y")
              epg2_day = epg_time_2.strftime("%d")
              epg2_month = epg_time_2.strftime("%m")
              epg2_year = epg_time_2.strftime("%Y")
              epg3_day = epg_time_2.strftime("%d")
              epg3_month = epg_time_2.strftime("%m")
              epg3_year = epg_time_2.strftime("%Y")
              half_hour = str(epg1_day + "/" + epg1_month + "/" + epg1_year + " " + epg_time1)
              one_hour = str(epg2_day + "/" + epg2_month + "/" + epg2_year + " " + epg_time2)
              one_hour_half = str(epg3_day + "/" + epg3_month + "/" + epg3_year + " " + epg_time3)


         #Store the times and date in the list....
         self.epg_time_1.append(half_hour)
         self.epg_time_2.append(one_hour)
         self.epg_time_3.append(one_hour_half)
```

What I'm expected the code to do is to change to the previous day date for each string that I get from the button objects when I call the EPG_time(self) function. If the `epg_time_1` and `epg_time_2` show the strings `11:00PM` and `11:30PM`, I want to set the time and date to `29/08/2017 11:00PM` for `epg_time_1` and `29/08/2017 11:30PM` for the `epg_time_2`. If the `epg_time_3` show the string `12:00AM` then I want to add it to the next day date with the time `30/08/2017 12:00AM`.

In the next 24 hours if the `epg_time_1` and `epg_time_2` show the strings `11:00PM` and `11:30PM`, I want to set the time and date to `30/08/2017 11:00PM` for `epg_time_1` and `30/08/2017 11:30PM` for the `epg_time_2`. If the `epg_time_3` show the string `12:00AM` then I want to set to the next day date with the time `1/09/2017 12:00AM`

If the `epg_time_1` and `epg_time_2` show the strings `11:30PM` and `12:00AM`, I want to change to the previous date for `epg_time_1` which it is `29/08/2017 11:30PM` and `30/08/2017 12:00AM`. It will be depends on the time and date when I have stored the strings in the list.

Can you please tell me an example how I could use to change the date to the previous date and add to the next day date using in python?

Comment: Can you please consolidate this text a bit? It seems that really all you need here is to convert your strings into datetimes using `strptime`. All the logic of days changing would be handled by the datetime module itself.

Comment: Right, I can probably put something together here as an example but I think it's impossible to properly answer your question from what is presented. I will have to make some assumptions; you get a list of 3 strings representing different datetimes, you need to add a constant factor of days (between 1 and 6) to these, and you want the datetimes to reflect this change?

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of text in your question that makes it hard to pinpoint the issue exactly. However, it appears to boil down to adding a variable number of days to a particular date and ensuring that the month is also updated (if necessary).

You should use the `datetime.datetime.strptime()` method to convert your dates to datetimes, which makes it trivial to add `timedelta` (you use both `timedelta` and `strftime` but miss this crucial method) and then just convert back to a string.

```
import datetime as dt

def add_days(datelist, days_to_add):
    # Convert the strings to datetime objects
    datelist = [dt.datetime.strptime(item, '%d/%m/%Y %I:%M%p') 
                for item in datelist]

    # Add a variable number of days (can be negative) to the datetimes
    mod_dates = [item + dt.timedelta(days=days_to_add) for item in datelist]

    # Convert back to strings
    str_dates = [dt.datetime.strftime(item, '%d/%m/%Y %I:%M%p')
                 for item in mod_dates]
    return str_dates

# This is the list right at the top of your question
a = ['29/08/2017 11:30PM', '30/08/2017 12:00AM', '30/08/2017 12:30AM']

print("Start:")
print(a)
b = add_days(a, 1)
print("After 1 call:")
print(b)
c = add_days(b, 1)
print("After 2 calls:")
print(c)
```